# Using 2 eventlisteners to change website's background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background of a website by moving the mouse to the upper (turns to orange) or lower (turns to blue) half of the screen.
It seems to work the way I imagined, but there's one problem: As soon as the blue event was triggered, I can't change it back to orange. It works the opposite way tho: So I can move the mouse to the top of the screen and it turns orange, then I move it to the lower part and it turns blue, but won't turn back to orange anymore:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  .orange-theme {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .blue-theme {
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:50vh">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="orange" id="change-background-orange"/>
</div>
<img src="http://www.example.png" class="wp-image-124" style="float:centre;width:100%"/>
<div style="height:50vh">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="blue" id="change-background-blue"/>
</div>

<script>
 document.getElementById("change-background-orange").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
  document.body.classList.add("orange-theme");
});

 document.getElementById("change-background-blue").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
  document.body.classList.add("blue-theme");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also wondering, if there is any way to position the mouse pointer right in the centre of the page, when the site is being loaded. Because otherwise it might instantly change the colour. I'd prefer the website to be plain white, with only the image visible, as long as the mouse isn't moved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to remove previously set class before adding a new one: `document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme")`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the css class you don't want while adding the css class you do want each time - ie:

```
document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");
document.body.classList.add("orange-theme");
```

```js
document.getElementById("change-background-orange").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
  document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");
  document.body.classList.add("orange-theme");
});

 document.getElementById("change-background-blue").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
  document.body.classList.remove("orange-theme");
  document.body.classList.add("blue-theme");
});
```

```css
.orange-theme {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .blue-theme {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div style="height:50vh">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="orange" id="change-background-orange"/>
</div>
<img src="http://www.example.png" class="wp-image-124" style="float:centre;width:100%"/>
<div style="height:50vh">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="blue" id="change-background-blue"/>
</div>
```

But this might be more fun: Use a single `mousemove` listener and animate the body background using css `transition`. Rather than an IF/ELSE statement you can use the mouse position detection as the `force` parameter in `classList.toggle`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

```js
let c = document.querySelector("#container");
c.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("blue-theme", (e.offsetY < c.clientHeight / 2));
  document.body.classList.toggle("orange-theme", (e.offsetY >= c.clientHeight / 2));
});
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.orange-theme {
  background-color: orange;
}

.blue-theme {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:50vh" id="container">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="orange" id="change-background-orange" />
</div>
<img src="http://www.example.png" class="wp-image-124" style="float:centre;width:100%" />
<div style="height:50vh">
  <button style="height:100%;width:100vw;opacity:0" class="blue" id="change-background-blue" />
</div>
```

Comment: if/else could also be combined using `toggle(className, force)`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks to both of you. It works.
I am still confused about the positioning and height of all the elements tho. Now I set the height of the buttons to 40vh each and img to 20vh. So I'd expect that the image is perfectly centred and no scrolling is possible. But in fact scrolling is enabled and the image is somewhere in the lower third of the page. How comes?

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks so much. I've never used the `force` param in `toggle` before.

Comment: @22TTT22 - hard to say without viewing it in a regular (non-snippet) page. Right click your elements, inspect and see what the web inspector thinks is going on... ?

Comment: You are right. Using transition and toggle makes it look way better. But I think there's something wrong with clientHeight, because the transition doesn't happen right at the edge from the first to second half. You can check it out on https://www.ideenschmelze.de/?page_id=218

Comment: I looked and the issue is you're putting the listener on `#container` like my example.  If you look at the inspector `#container` only occupies the top part of the screen. The listener should probably be on `body` - which I would have done in the snippet but it doesn't work the same there. Short story: put the listener on `document.querySelector("body")` or some other top-level `height:100vh` element

Comment: @Kinglish I changed it to body, but that makes it worse. Now there's only a small area on the bottom left side, that switches it to blue. That's weird, because the body element is also visible on the right side. I can't find a top level element that works.